# In what condition print('done') statement will execute and will not execute?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, except, try-finally

I'm bit confused that in which case does the finally block along with the `print('done'`) statement will execute. Because when the try block will execute then only the finally block executes along with the output but when there is some exception then the except block will execute along with finally block and
`print('done')` statement.
Also if we write print statement in try block then `print('done')` statement will execute all time.
Something like this,

```
def division(x,y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except TypeError:
        print('error type')
    except ValueError:
        print('value error')
    finally:
        print('final')
    print('done')

division(23,4)
```

Output:-

```
result  5.75
final
done
```

---

```
def division(x,y):
    try:
        return x/y
    except TypeError:
        print('type error')
    except ValueError:
        print('value error')
    finally:
        print('final')
    print('done')

division(23,4)

division('12',3)
```

Output:-

```
final

error type
final
done
```

Comment: “final” is *always* printed. “done” is only printed if you don’t `return` from the function before, which is only the case if one of the two expected error types is raised and caught.

Answer (score 1):

by using `return x/y` you are causing the function to stop. Thus, if `return x/y` succeeds, 'done' is not printed. 'final' is still printed because it is within a finally block which executes unconditionally.

However, if you cause `return x/y` to create a TypeError or a ValueError, nothing is returned and instead you go into the except blocks. After finishing the except block, the function moves onto finally block and then to the `print('done')`

Thus, the condition under which `print('done')` is executed is one in which either x or y does not support the divide action.